# ¿Cambiar color texto main menu android?

Tags: android, android-layout, menú

Quiero cambiar el color del texto de un `item` que agrupa un `menu`.

El xml es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mi_cuenta"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_mi_cuenta"
            android:title="@string/mi_cuenta" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/herramientas">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_configuracion"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_config"
                android:title="@string/configuraci_n" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Quiero cambiar el color del item:

```
<item android:title="@string/herramientas">
```

Asi es como está actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, `Herramientas` sale en negro y como el fondo también es negro a penas se ve. No encuentro ninguna propiedad para cambiarlo. El color del `item` 'Mis datos' y 'Configuración' lo cambio programaticalmente de la siguiente forma a partir de un archivo `json` externo de un servidor:

```
colorElegido = getParseColor(json.getString("colorMenuLateral"));
navigationView.setBackgroundColor(colorElegido);

colorElegido = getParseColor(json.getString("colorFuenteMenuLateral"));
ColorStateList colorList = getColorList(colorElegido);

navigationView.setItemTextColor(colorList);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/fondologo"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<!-- Content Container -->

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Espero llegar a tiempo de ayudar.

A mi me ha costado encontrarlo